# Range contact chord lengths when $\frac{x^2}{25}+\frac{y^2}{16}=1$ is touching a circle inside

Tags: geometry

A circle passes through a point on $x$ axis vertically ( like point  $(3,0) $ shown) and has its center on $y=0$ and touches the ellipse at $A$ and $B$. What is the range of chord of contact $AB$ ?

Known answer: $$ 4 < AB <7 \,$$

My approach in the sketch
[image: my approach]

EDIT:

A variable circle centered on $x$ axis touches an ellipse $ (a=5,b=4),$ passes through  a typical point such as $(3,0)$ as shown. Find range of distance between ellipse/circle tangent points ( length of contact chord ).

[image]

Comment: I have assumed the parametric coordinates of the ellipse, so than we to find maximum value of 8sin theta, can't figure out what to do next

Comment: Is it only touch or also intersection is acceptable?

Comment: The circle only touches

Comment: I have placed a comment in your question area as the sketch given is  too big for the comments area. If not ok, feel free to roll it back.

Comment: To find the range, $AB$ first set up equations of circle and ellipse. Contact occurs when discriminant vanishes while solving for intersection points.

Comment: Related to https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1972994/265466.