# Points within an ellipse on the globe

Tags: geometry, conic-sections, spherical-geometry

I'm interested in finding the equation that will tell me if a given geographical coordinate (lat1, lon1) is within an ellipse centered on a another coordinate (lat2, lon2) with a given semi-major axis (a) and a semi-minor axis (b) *and* a rotation (rot) in radians.

I've found equations for [dealing with points inside of an unrotated ellipse](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/76457/check-if-a-point-is-within-an-ellipse), but none that take into account the curve of the Earth, e.g., using the [haversine formula](https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html), nor any that involve a rotation.

I thought I could puzzle through this, but I've hit the limits of my own geometry... the goal is to turn this into a SQL query, for whatever that is worth.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7946187/point-and-ellipse-rotated-position-test-algorithm

Comment: If you can get the ellipse equation and project it into XY - the sign of the value inserted in the equation will tell you if it is inside or outside the perimeter of the ellipse.

Comment: Thanks @Aretino — that code is great, except I don't really understand how to deal with latitude/longitude issue. If I treat the lat/lon just naively as points, I get very warped results (not great circle results) as I move towards the poles.

Comment: Do you know how to compute the distance between two points on the sphere? If so, you could find foci $F_1$, $F_2$ and check if $PF_1+PF_2\lessgtr 2a$.

Answer (score 2):

If the centre $C$ of the ellipse has longitude $\phi$ and colatitude $\theta$ then its coordinates are
$$C=R(\sin\theta\cos\phi,\sin\theta\sin\phi,\cos\theta),$$
where $R=\ $radius of the sphere.

The foci $F_1$, $F_2$ of the ellipse are located on the major axis, at a distance $c=\sqrt{a^2-b^2}$ from the centre. If the major axis is rotated of an angle $\alpha$ (counterclockwise) with respect to the North direction, then the coordinates of the foci are:
$$
F_{1,2}=R
\pmatrix{\pm\cos \alpha \sin \gamma \cos \phi \cos \theta\mp\sin \alpha \sin \gamma \sin \phi+\cos \gamma \cos \phi \sin \theta \\
\pm\cos \alpha \sin \gamma \sin\phi \cos \theta\pm\sin \alpha \sin \gamma \cos \phi+\cos \gamma \sin \phi \sin \theta \\
\cos \gamma \cos \theta\mp\cos \alpha \sin \gamma \sin \theta},
$$
where $\gamma=c/R$ is the central angle corresponding to the distance between the centre and a focus.

To check if a point $P$ on the sphere is inside the ellipse, compute its distances $d_1$, $d_2$ from the foci and check if $d_1+d_2\le2a$.